# CLR20r3 System.Data.SqlClient.Sql for C# App

Tags: c#

The app works fine on my dev box but I take it to the end user's computer it gives this error.  I published it and installed it on the target computer as well.

```
 SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("SERVER=SERVERWITHDB;DATABASE=DATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

Is this the correct way to go about setting up a sql connection?

Comment: No, read the connectionstring from the exe.config file, do not hardcode it in your code. By the way, what error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to build the connection string inside your code (instead of configuring it in your exe.config file), you could use a [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "SERVERWITHDB",
    InitialCatalog = "DATABASENAME",
    IntegratedSecurity = true
};
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
```

You'll see that the connection string you showed in your question uses the wrong key words. A valid connection string for a `SqlConnection` looks like this:

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERWITHDB;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True");
```

So the keywords are:

- `Data Source` for the database server name
- `Initial Catalog` for the database to use
- `Integrated Security` set to `True` for Windows authentication and `False` for SQL server authentication
- `User ID` for the user name (SQL server authentication only)
- `Password` for the password (SQL server authentication only)

Comment: I still get the following error:
  Problem Event Name:                        CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:                       POC1.exe
  Problem Signature 02:                       1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:                       56f1509c
  Problem Signature 04:                       System.Data
  Problem Signature 05:                       4.0.30319.34209
  Problem Signature 06:                       53489aad
  Problem Signature 07:                       25bd
  Problem Signature 08:                       27
  Problem Signature 09:                       System.Data.SqlClient.Sql

Comment: Well this error message does not tell me very much. I don't think this comes from your connection string. I suggest to add some more error handling to your code (e.g. a `try/catch` block around the db operations) and log the exception (including stack trace!). Then update your question with the necessary information or ask a new question if that's a totally different error.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to check that the network user has access rights to SQL server (your integrated security was set to true).